# Update Node.js CLI from < 7.7.0 to 7.10.0 advised by Google: Error: Cannot find module 'google-auth-library'

Tags: node.js, firebase, npm, google-cloud-functions

I got an email from Google:

> We are writing because one of your Firebase projects has HTTP Cloud Functions that were deployed using the Firebase CLI.
>   After January 15, 2020, if you use any version of the Firebase CLI lower than 7.7.0 to deploy a new HTTP or Callable Cloud Function, that function will require you to explicitly grant public access through Cloud IAM permissions. Existing HTTP Cloud Functions will not be affected by this change.
>   What’s next?
>   Before you attempt to deploy any functions, update your Firebase CLI to the latest version (at least 7.7.0, released November 7, 2019), by running: 
>   1.  npm install --global firebase-tools, and then
>   2.  firebase --version to confirm that you're on a version of 7.7.0 or higher.
>   Once you have done this, functions deployed with the Firebase CLI will continue to be public by default.

When I run firebase --version I get now:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638 throw err;

Error: Cannot find module 'google-auth-library'
        at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
        at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
        at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
        at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Wolfgang\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\google-auto-auth\index.js:5:18)
        at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
        at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
        at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
```

What can I do? The module `google-auth-library` exists.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve the problem:
The module 'goggle-auth-library' exists (also on C:) but CLI does not work.

When i installed the module 'goggle-auth-library' **globally** with -g it worked but some other modules are not found and i installed them too globally. Now it works.